Add before and after button label on a bootstrap toggle button
How do I change button label before and after clicking on a bootstrap toggle switch/button? Without using jquery, javascript. Just using bootstrap, there must be a feature for this feature rich bootstrap.
Before label: Show list
After label: Hide list


<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div class="container d-flex mb-4 p-4"> 
        <div class="btn-1 m-2"> 
            <input type="checkbox" class="btn-check" 
                id="btn-check" autocomplete="off"> 
            <label class="btn btn-primary" for="btn-check"> 
                Show list 
            </label> 
        </div> 




Here it is with CSS:


/* Hide the original text */

.toggle-label {
  position: relative;
  color: transparent !important;
  /* to hide the original text */
}


/* Create the pseudo-element to display the text */

.toggle-label::after {
  content: attr(data-off);
  /* Default text */
  color: white;
  /* Adjust color as needed */
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 50%;
  /*to position center*/
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  /*to position center*/
  width: 88px;
  /*the width of the button*/
}


/* Change the content based on the checkbox state */

#btn-check:checked+.toggle-label::after {
  content: attr(data-on);
}

.btn-primary {
  max-width: 88px;
  /*to make it responsive*/
  width: 100%;
  height: 38px;
}
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container d-flex mb-4 p-4">
  <div class="btn-1 m-2">
    <input type="checkbox" class="btn-check" id="btn-check" autocomplete="off">
    <label class="btn btn-primary toggle-label" data-on="Hide list" data-off="Show list" for="btn-check"> <!--notice the data-* -->
          Show list
        </label>
  </div>
</div>




toggle-label is common class, I can use it for other buttons too. Thanks!
